# Insert column vaues in Row sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I am spliting '0021C-15563017-2' on '-' and 
I want to insert (`0021c`,`15563017`,`2` ) in T2(clntcode,certno.depcode) ,see image .
I tried the cross apply to insert the split value in a row of the table(img 2) but not working.

The query I have used:

```
SELECT CLNTCODE, certno, depcode  
FROM T2  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT('0021C-15563017-2', '-');
```

[image: img 1]

Comment: check whether table T2 having data or not

Comment: no it doesnot have data

Comment: then how you expect data what you need please explain clearly

Comment: are you asking about inserting those ( '0021c','15563017','2' ) data into your T2 table?

Comment: i want to insert split value of ('0021C-15563017-2 ,-) in a tableshown in image .

Comment: @i3lai3la yes you are right

Comment: You have to write insert query then.

Comment: @Rahulray check the answer now

Comment: What is the generic format of the string?  You have shown one value, but not explained the general format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not using `STRING_SPLIT` here, because it might be difficult to fish out the three components from your hyphen-separated string.  Instead, I recommend using `CHARINDEX`:

```
WITH T2 AS (
    SELECT '0021C-15563017-2' AS col
)

SELECT
    LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('-', col) - 1) AS CLNTCODE,
    SUBSTRING(col,
              CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('-', col, CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1) -
                  CHARINDEX('-', col) - 1) AS certno,
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('-', col, CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1) + 1, LEN(col))
        AS depcode
FROM T2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that `STRING_SPLIT` would be difficult to use here, because it is hard to address a given record from the table valued response from that function.

Comment: what is col in this?

Comment: @Rahulray [Check the demo](https://rextester.com/XTFZ61719).  I assume the column containing your string is called `col`.

Comment: this is returning the right value ,but not inserting the data in T2 table

Comment: Then use an `INSERT INTO...SELECT` followed by my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into t2 (CLNTCODE, certno, depcode  )
select *
from 
(
select *,row_number() over (order by value ) as rn  from STRING_SPLIT('0021C-15563017-2', '-')
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

Comment: This would coincidentally happen to work here, because `0021C` is less than `15563017-2`, which in turn is less than `2`.  If the string were `15563017-0021C-2`, then I would expect this solution to not work.

Comment: Don't use `STRING_SPLIT` if the order or sequence of the rows return is important. There are many other implementation of similar function around

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
    CLNTCODE VARCHAR(25), 
    certno VARCHAR(25), 
    depcode VARCHAR(25)
    );

WITH StrTbl(Col1, Col3, Str) AS
(
SELECT LEFT(Str, CHARINDEX('-', Str) - 1) Col1,
       LEFT(REVERSE(Str), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Str)) - 1) Col3,
       Str
FROM
    (
      SELECT '0021C-15563017-2' AS Str
      UNION
      SELECT '0021C-1-2'
    ) T
)

INSERT INTO YourTable (CLNTCODE, certno, depcode)
SELECT Col1,
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Str, Col1, ''), Col3, ''), '-', '') AS Col2,
       Col3
FROM StrTbl;

SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
```

Results:

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|    | CLNTCODE |  certno  | depcode |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|  1 | 0021C    | 15563017 |       2 |
|  2 | 0021C    |        1 |       2 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/HPAJR93422)**

Comment: I feel as though I've seen this answer somewhere :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I feel like someone think so and DV my answer cause he think I copy/paste his own, which is wrong :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of the triple call to `CHARINDEX()` too, as it can be avoided :)

Comment: @Sami this returning wrong result for string '0021C-1-2', it should return - 0021C,1,2 but it returning 0021C,1-2,2

Answer (score 0):

Below approach can also be used if suited for someone.

```
INSERT INTO T2 (CLNTCODE, certno, depcode)
SELECT LEFT('0021C-15563017-2', CHARINDEX('-', '0021C-15563017-2') - 1) AS CLNTCODE,
LEFT(REPLACE('0021C-15563017-2', LEFT('0021C-15563017-2', CHARINDEX('-', '0021C-15563017-2')), ''), CHARINDEX('-', REPLACE('0021C-15563017-2', LEFT('0021C-15563017-2', CHARINDEX('-', '0021C-15563017-2')), '')) - 1) AS certno,
LEFT(REVERSE('0021C-15563017-2'), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE('0021C-15563017-2')) - 1) AS depcode
```

Comment: this is returning wrong result for this 0021C-1-2, it is returning - >clntcode=0021C,certno=1-2,depcode=2.

Comment: For me it is returning correctly. clntcode=0021C, certno=1 and depcode=2. Please try again there might be some other issue. Just replace all the occurrences of '0021C-15563017-2' with '0021C-1-2'. Let me know if you still face any problem.